# Python(3.x): print(string , end='') results in highlighted modulo symbol %

Tags: python-3.x, printing, zsh

Run below code snippet(print_end.py). The output is as expected except ending with a highlighted modulo symbol %.

How come this %? I have no idea where to find doc reference.

If adding one more line `print()` it will get rid of % symbol.

```
# txt = input('Give me anything: ')
txt = 'GitHub is NO.1!' 
print(f'print before loop: {txt}')
for s in txt:
    print(s, end='')
# print()
```

Pyenv env Python 3.8.0 **output:**
[image]

Conda env Python 3.7.3 **output:**
[image]

**More info:**
macOS Catalina 10.15.1, zsh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I report here an answer written by @Leiaz on unix.stackexchange (for reference: [Why ZSH ends a line with a highlighted percent symbol?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167582/why-zsh-ends-a-line-with-a-highlighted-percent-symbol)):

This happens because it is a "partial line". And by default [zsh goes to the next line to avoid covering it with the prompt](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Prompting).

> When a partial line is preserved, by default you will see an
> inverse+bold character at the end of the partial line: a "%" for a
> normal user or a "#" for root. If set, the shell parameter
> PROMPT_EOL_MARK can be used to customize how the end of partial lines
> are shown.

So it's not Python, this behaviour is related to how ZSH is configured. If you run the same script in bash you will see a different behaviour.